# Again, user config files C#

Tags: c#, configuration-files

I have a large config file (user) that i needed to go to the right location and have some default values.

Since i have a installer class, i added some parameter setting to the config file in it, but created the config files in the installers folder.

What is the best way to ensure these default parameters will be written only once, and in the right location?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A standard way of using defaults in the app.config. For example, here's a default value per version I use to ensure the code copies user settings between upgrades:

```
<userSettings>
    <Software.Namespace.Properties.UserSettings>
      <setting name="RequiresUpgrade" serializeAs="String">
        <value>True</value>
      </setting>
    </Software.Namespace.Properties.UserSettings>
  </userSettings>
  <-- .... -->
  <userSettings>
    <Software.Namespace.Properties.UserSettings>
      <setting name="RequiresUpgrade" serializeAs="String">
        <value>True</value>
      </setting>
    </Software.Namespace.Properties.UserSettings>
  </userSettings>
</configuration>
```

You will need to add a .settings file to your project, or go to your project properties -> Settings and configure them from there.

The location of the user's own settings file is usually placed within their AppSettings folder in their profile. I'm not sure if this can be changed, but I seem to remember reading out it.

***EDIT***

There's some more information about it here: [Application Settings Architecture](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8eyb2ct1.aspx)

It also shows the following example if you want to keep it simple:

```
[UserScopedSetting()]
[DefaultSettingValue("white")]
public Color BackgroundColor
{
    get
    {
        return ((Color)this["BackgroundColor"]);
    }
    set
    {
        this["BackgroundColor"] = (Color)value;
    }
}
```

And this looks like it's very important to note when using this (quote):

> For a Windows Forms-based application
>   copied onto the local computer,
>   app.exe.config will reside in the same
>   directory as the base directory of the
>   application's main executable file,
>   and user.config **will reside in the
>   location specified by the
>   Application.LocalUserAppDataPath
>   property**. For an application installed
>   by means of ClickOnce, both of these
>   files will reside in the ClickOnce
>   Data Directory underneath
>   %InstallRoot%\Documents and
>   **Settings\username\Local Settings**.
>
> The storage location of these files is
>   slightly different **if a user has
>   enabled roaming profiles**, which
>   enables a user to define different
>   Windows and application settings when
>   he or she is using other computers
>   within a domain. In that case, both
>   ClickOnce applications and
>   non-ClickOnce applications will have
>   their app.exe.config and user.config
>   files stored under
>   %InstallRoot%\Documents and
>   **Settings\username\Application Data**.