# where are C# setting file values are saved? it's not in the appName.config

Tags: c#-2.0, configuration-files

I'm using the settings files in C#. and cannot find where are the values saved.
the app works perfect but when I want to change manually the values in the appName.cpnfig it doesn't load/save the values there but in some other place.
does anyone know where?

Answer (score 0):

Possible duplicate of [Again, user config files C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2515146/again-user-config-files-c).

It depend on your Windows version.  In Windows 7, I have it under C:\Users\tim\AppData\Local... as user.config.  See http://msdn.microsoft.com/En-US/library/8eyb2ct1.aspx for detailed information.

> Settings File Locations
>
> The location of the app.exe.config and
>   user.config files will differ based on
>   how the application is installed. For
>   a Windows Forms-based application
>   copied onto the local computer,
>   app.exe.config will reside in the same
>   directory as the base directory of the
>   application's main executable file,
>   and user.config will reside in the
>   location specified by the
>   Application.LocalUserAppDataPath
>   property. For an application installed
>   by means of ClickOnce, both of these
>   files will reside in the ClickOnce
>   Data Directory underneath
>   %InstallRoot%\Documents and
>   Settings\username\Local Settings.
>
> The storage location of these files is
>   slightly different if a user has
>   enabled roaming profiles, which
>   enables a user to define different
>   Windows and application settings when
>   he or she is using other computers
>   within a domain. In that case, both
>   ClickOnce applications and
>   non-ClickOnce applications will have
>   their app.exe.config and user.config
>   files stored under
>   %InstallRoot%\Documents and
>   Settings\username\Application Data.
>
> For more information about how the
>   Application Settings feature works
>   with the new deployment technology,
>   see ClickOnce and Application
>   Settings. For more information about
>   the ClickOnce Data Directory, see
>   Accessing Local and Remote Data in
>   ClickOnce Applications.

Comment: I can find the config file that's in the same location of the exe but that config file is not the config that the app uses.

Comment: You need to look in Application.LocalUserAppDataPath or %InstallRoot%\Documents and Settings\username\Local Settings.

Comment: How to get %InstallRoot%?

Answer (score 0):

Default settings' values are placed in the auto-generated, strongly-typed version of them (for example, if your settings file is "Some.settings", strongly-typed version would be "SomeSettings.Designer.cs").

You can override them by adding a configuration section in the app.config like this:

```
<configuration>
  <configSections>
      <section
        name="SomeNamespace.SomeSettings"
        type="System.Configuration.ClientSettingsSection, System, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089"
        requirePermission="false"
      />
    </sectionGroup>
  </configSections>

  <applicationSettings>
    <SomeNamespace.SomeSettings>
       <setting name="SomeExistingSetting" serializeAs="String">
        <value>Some new value</value>
      </setting>
  </applicationSettings>
<configuration>
```